# Did I commit zina or no?

Tags: sex, zina

My boyfriend has inserted the tip of his penis inside my vagina and I’m not sure if all of it went in or just part of it . What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is 
Firstly bieng a Muslim I dont think you were allowed to date and thats completely haram to get naked in front of anyone except  your husband where as you got naked infront of your bf and your private parts touched